# Cannot remove white bar in the top website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with removing the navigation bar completely from the website
when I remove it from html it just makes (!) another white bar in the bottom

It also appears when I resize the chrome tab

I want to get rid of all of this..

Canva website example: https://www.canva.com/design/DAFCSBRJ9Oc/J8MP4clHYoNIJNTN2wDFyA/view?website#4

I have already looked up google but my limited experience in code can't help me here.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add display none on the div with class "EYoDFQ qrdleA"

```
<div class="EYoDFQ qrdleA" style="display: none;">
...
</div>
```

[image]
2) In the div with class "yIDCqA" turn off height;

```
<div class="yIDCqA">
......
</div>
```

[image]
3) Result

[image]

Comment: Thank You :)
Would you mind telling me how to get rid of the scroll bar as well?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that the body may not be spanning across the full height of window. try giving height 100vh to main container and adjust the height of inner child DOM accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Altough removing from HTML should work, Canva their website builder could be injecting this navigation bar, resulting into the problem you are having.

Add this CSS rule to completely hide the navigation bar.

```
.QnQnDA {
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*please provide the code in a snippet included in the answer to help future programmers as well.*

In your case just remove the <div class="QnQnDA" ...  and the white bar will be removed but depending on the window size of the browser you are seeing it you will see a white bar at the bottom because there is a filler element that fills everything below the content (element with class=_2qaR-A). If you want to change this color assign a CSS style or an inline style to this element or choose another way to deal with the remaining space below the content.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked you attached the example and You can add the style to the main.
And I think that it needs to style for responsive.
Add this style
body {height:100vh;}

If you have any questions, let me know.